# DDD Entity - are two entities with default identity considered equal

Tags: c#, entity, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, iequatable

I want to apply/practice DDD with my new project hence I am creating those typical DDD base classes, i.e., `Entity`, `ValueObject`, `AggregateRoot` and so on.

**Question:**
When you have the Entity base object implement `IEquatable`, should two entities with default value of the identity (Id) be considered as **Not equal** or **equal**?

For example, I use `Guid` type for the identity

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid LocalId { get; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity, IEquatable<Entity>
{
    public Guid LocalId { get; private set; }

    protected Entity()
    {
        this.LocalId = Guid.Empty;
    }

    protected Entity(Guid id)
    {
        if (Guid.Empty == id)
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        this.LocalId = id;
    }

    public bool Equals(Entity other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // **Question** - should I return false or true here?
        if (other.LocalId == Guid.Empty && this.LocalId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (other.LocalId == this.LocalId);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(Entity)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((Entity)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.LocalId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator==(Entity left, Entity right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(Entity left, Entity right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question not related to your question: is it a c# thing to define this base clases? In `PHP`, I like to a avoid inheritance, especially in domain objects (entities, aggregate roots, value objects).

Comment: @Constantin: no, it isn't a C# thing :) --- it is a design choice made by some folks.  I don't use these myself and wouldn't recommend it either.  Does't hurt but also doesn't really add much value IMHO.

Comment: @David, to answer your question: technically the "objects" are the same but from a business point-of-view having an entity/aggregate without a key makes little sense and the equality, or lack thereof, has no meaning.

Comment: Good. I'm glad :)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU: It's true that creating a base class for, for example, Entity is just a matter of your design and programming style. I did that because I am seeing all my entities would have the same type of identity, GUID. Some forks like to have a generic Entity base class so that you can pass different types for the identity.

Comment: @EbenRoux: So in other words, you would like / prefer to return false and say "Nope, two entities that have no ids are not equal"?

Comment: @David: I'd probably go with an exception.  Would there really be any sense in comparing invalid entities.  There is quite a fine line between what is a technical requirement vs what is truly specific to the domain being modeled.  Is your domain expert concerned about this aspect?  I doubt it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the book on this then remember that:

> An object that is not defined by its attributes, but rather by a
>   thread of continuity and its identity.

Now, in this context identity means **"the property of objects that distinguishes them from other objects"**, which in most cases means the entity primary key (if your entities are persisted in a database) or some kind of Id attribute, in most cases a GUID will do the trick.

So to answer your question:

1. Yes, they're the same entity.
2. Be careful with how you create your
   Id's

Comment: Then should I remove the empty constructor Entity() so that I can force the sub classes to pass an Id into it?

Comment: I would, but that's just a matter of style.